# Masking configuration of physical workstation

Tags: windows, privacy, anonymity, reverse-engineering, debugging

Environment:

1. Physical workstation, HP, Dell, etc
2. Windows 7,8,10, no matter
3. Windows executables

Our goal:

For additional privacy, is it possible to wipe/change all configuration that can be read by windows executable? (Including mac address, list of software, keys, fonts and other hardware related information) basically I’m interested if there is such software already developed to generate fake configuration for windows OS.

Please share any ideas you have on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

There are myriad of ways to fingerprint a system from the OS version, registry entries, functionality advertised, driver versions, applications, hardware available (chipsets, drivers associated, etc.).

Trying to fool *all* methods of fingerprinting a system is likely a task that's not worthwhile.

You may accomplish a similar result by sandboxing applications which you would like to hide this information from.

Alternatively you could use a virtual machine since they typically look very similar to each other (hardware emulation) but that doesn't hide the OS or other applications.

Attempting to fool applications can also lead to unexpected and potentially damaging behavior. A program which thinks it's running on Windows 98 is going to behave differently than one that thinks it's in Windows 10. This may result in security issues if programs attempt to use "compatible" but insecure methods (e.g. SSL 2, or 3 instead of TLS; MD5, RC4, etc. )

Comment: I thought the same, but using virtualization and sandboxes is useless if application checks environment and blocks itself from executing.

Comment: @skinnercid I agree, there's a lot if ways to detect that an application is running in a restricted environment. Is there any reason in particular you're trying to do this?  Are you studying malware? Or is this just to be "extra cautious"?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but SSLv1 was never released. Netscape found severe security issues with it internally and created SSLv2, without ever having made v1 public. No application could "downgrade" to SSLv1.